# Experimental setup of PostgresXL on Kubernetes with Local volumes

Tags: database, kubernetes, scaling

I'm making a [Gedankenexperiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment) about deploying [PostgresXL](https://www.postgres-xl.org/) on Kubernetes (k8s) where each datanode uses **local (Directly Attached)** storage.

---

Imagine we have the following nodes:

- **2x** highend machines with blazingly fast Optane DC SSD and NVDIMM. These nodes are registered with k8s and labelled as `type: datanode`.
- **1x** machine registered with k8s and labelled as `type: GTM`.
- **2x** machines registered with k8s and labelled as `type: coodinator`.

Let's say that each label creates a "node group" (e.g. the `type: datanode` label makes a group with two nodes).
Let's also suppose that each node has a `/data` mount point (in the host OS) that is mapped to its underlying fastest disk (or LVM logical volume).

I would deploy an architecture like this one:

```
                        --------------
                        |   gtm_0    |
                        --------------
                       / |          | \
                     /   |          |   \
                   /     |          |     \
                 /       |          |       \
               /         |          |         \
             /           |          |           \
           /             |          |             \
         /               |          |               \
       /       ------------        ------------      \
      |        | coord_0  |        | coord_1  |       |
      |        ------------        ------------       |
      |       /             \    /             \      |
      |     /                 \/                 \    |
------------      ------------/\------------      ------------
|  data_0  |     /                          \     |  data_1  |
------------ ----                            ---- ------------
```

Which cames from a [postgres-xl docker compose image](https://github.com/pavouk-0/postgres-xl-docker).

I want to eventually scale horizontally each of the three nodes categories and I need a stable name for each one, so I would create three `StatefulSet`s (each one backed by the same headless service): `ss-datanodes`, `ss-gtms` and `ss-coords`.
In each of these `StatefulSet` the pod template would select only the relevant nodes (eg: the `type: datanode` nodes for the `ss-datanodes` pods) and have the appropriate image (eg: of the GTM for the `ss-gtms` set).

This would allow k8s to "shuffle" the pods within the same node group.

However I **don't want to use any NAS**, each pod must only use **DAS** to maximize performance.
To do so I create a `StorageClass` without provisioning and with a binding mode set to "WaitForFirstConsumer".
I would then create a **three** `PersistentVolume`s, these PVs would be of type [`local`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local), point to the `/data` mount point and differs only in the `nodeAffinity`.
I would also create a **three** `PersistenceVolumeClaim` (PVC) matching the companion PVs.

Finally, I would add the PVCs in the pods templates in the `StatefulSet`s.

This should allow k8s to:

- Schedule the components (GTM, Coordinator, DataNode) only in their node group.
- Shuffle the pods in their node group.
- Let the `/data` mount point be available on each pod.

I'm making the following assumption about PostgresXL:

- The components can be brought up in any order (e.g. coord_0, data_1, gtm_0, data_0, coord_1).
- Each component can handle the data written by another component of the same kind (e.g. data_0 and data_1 pods could be swapped and made to use the other one data and keep working). This doesn't seem unreasonable as the only identity a pod keeps is its hostname.

**Would this setup work for PostgresXL and what do I get by using k8s?**

One thing k8s is useful is HPA, which could be used to automatically add another datanode node and scale the `ss-datanodes` up.
However, all over the Internet, I read that state management is hard within k8s. But this setup isn't hard, so I must miss something.